# Laravel 7 Composer install error exception

Tags: php, laravel

While creating a new laravel project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 projectx` an error exception occurred

> [ErrorException]
> copy(/Users/me/.composer/cache/files/symfony/deprecation-contracts/99b9801994a098b194130905f1f0df2d1f43254c.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I deleted the vendor folder then ran `composer install` command again but ended up with the same error. This happened after `symfony/deprecation-contracts` is downloaded as you can see here

I need help me on the reason why this is happening and how to go about fixing it

Comment: You probably previously ran composer as root, and now you can't modify the cache file. Try `sudo composer clearcache` to see if that helps

Comment: @aynber thanks this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give full access of .composer to user.

```
sudo chown -R 'user-name' /home/'user-name'/.composer

example:-    sudo chown -R user /home/user/.composer
```

or

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/'user-name'/.composer

example:-    sudo chmod 777 -R /home/user/.composer
```

`user-name` is your system user-name.

use `sudo composer clearcache` to clear the caches.

Comment: The permission isn't the issue, I already checked and the user has the right permission already

Comment: Changed solutions :)